# Swimming routine for a person in very bad shape?

Tags: strength, cardio, swimming

I've been trying to find an answer to this but I couldn't. If this is a duplicate please accept my apologies and please show me the original question.

**A bit of background:**

I'm a developer in quite bad shape. Not specially fat, but very weak muscles which are causing me too many problems in the shoulders due to bad posture and weak support. Not too old (29 towards 30). I also have an old knee injury that forbids me to do things like football or running.

I've not trained before due to a mixture of lack of time plus lack of interest plus laziness plus some dislike for crowded gyms, but I've gotten to the point that I clearly see that I need to improve both my endurance and strength.

My aim is not to build a lot of muscle, simply to get to a healthy status with average endurance and strength, not looking for a 6-pack nor anything like this (at least not now)

**My question:**

I've been reading around an it seems that for my case swimming is the best activity. It would be kind to my knee while helping me build endurance and (to a minor extends) strength for my muscles, specially my back (which is relevant due to me being an IT guy). If I'm wrong, please correct me!

Now, **where can I find some training routines for swimming?From beginner to intermediate level.**

I've seen many routines for strength, cardio, etc but none specific to swimming. Is like if people assumes you now how to do it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Above everything else: don't overdo it, because you'll only get injured which means you won't be able to work out at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swimming is akin to running in that you don't define a single running routine per se; you run until tired and increase your duration as your endurance increases.

You define cardio activities and strength activities of which swimming could be one. Defining a specific routine leveraging ONLY swimming would withhold strength training which is a valuable component in bettering your posture along with your overall health.

If your focus is swimming; the routine can be simple. [Begin by using laps](http://stevendarien.wordpress.com/?s=swimming) as your mode of exercise and increase the length and duration of your laps as your endurance increases over time. A more [defined approach](http://www.fitnessmagazine.com/workout/cardio/no-treadmill/swimming-pool-workouts/?page=1) is also available if that suits you better.

Many individuals hold back in strength training for fear of becoming overly muscular. I can assure you that will not happen overnight and often times never happens for those attempting to reach that goal. Do not withhold your strength training as it is vital to your overall health and will go a long way in improving your posture.

Comment: True, swimming is pretty much like running. Though you'll have to follow a program if you want to see any further progress, but actually even that's the same in running!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a great answer :) On the Strength issue, though, I read that swimming, due to the water resistance, helped a bit. Of course not the same as squats, but it had a component which weak people like me would notice. Is that false?

Comment: @Pere You will notice it during the early stages of your swimming regimen; however swimming as a form of resistance will quickly tapper off and whole body strength training such as squats, dead lifts, pull-ups, push-ups will go a long way at that time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will start with swimming then and once I get a bit more fit move to strength training. Thanks very much guys! :)